# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin

I build app using Kotlin with MVVM architecture, and now i write Unit Test for my ViewModel, just use `JUnit` and `Mockito`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.0'
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.12.0'
}
```

But, when i try to run test, i got this following error :

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/compat/R$bool;
```

Here is my test class :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class RegistrationFragmentViewModelTest {
    var mViewModel: RegistrationFragmentViewModel? = null
    @Mock var mContext: Context? = null
    @Mock var mView: RegistrationView? = null

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        mViewModel = RegistrationFragmentViewModel(mContext!!, mView!!)
    }

    @Test
    fun AfterInput_InvalidFirstName_ShowFirstNameError() {
        // Given
        val firstName = "fa"
        val email = "fanjavaid@gmail.com"
        val password = "demo"

        // When
        mViewModel?.doRegister()

        // Then
        verify(mViewModel)?.validateInput()
        verify(mView)?.showFirstNameError(mContext?.resources?.getString(R.string.registration_error_email_format)!!)
    }
}
```

I still don't know why. Any ideas?
Thank you?